# how to add or remove pysnmp server users dynamically

Tags: authentication, user-management, pysnmp

I have a web based system that can add or remove users dynamically or change a user permissions.
also i want to add snmp support to this system based on those users. in simple way i can add previously available users via `addV3User` and `addVacmUser` but what about user recently added or permission changed users without restarting pysnmp service?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the functions that are complimentary to `addV3User` ([delV3User](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/entity/config.py#L204)) and `addVacmUser` ([delVacmUser](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/master/pysnmp/entity/config.py#L540)).

Pretty much any of these SNMP user management *add** functions have their *del** counterpart.

Comment: ok. that is right that we can use these functions to add or delete users. but i need an event like `on_new_request` to pass a callback function to it that contains routines that read user data from database and add or remove snmpV3 users.

Comment: for example if i patch `sendMessage` function in `AbstractTransportDispatcher` class to dynamically add user it work well. but i am not sure this is right way or in other hands i sure this is wrong way.

Comment: may you help me @ilya-etingof

Comment: I found user information store in a table in snmp agent. what about if i create this table dynamically i will achieve my goal?